# Citrix style winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to build a citrix like win-form means i have a win-form inside which i want to run Cmd prompt. I want a win-form to have 3 - 4 tab and each tab having cmd prompt inside which some external jobs will run and show the status.

The CMD prompt should run inside the win-form only i don't want to use Process.Start() because it will open outside win-form.

I am Looking for some help or link because not able to find something on google. Or if anyone can suggest someother way

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107683/controling-cmd-exe-from-winforms

Comment: Thanks Tijesunimi.. I was not sure what to google :P therefore was not able to find what i wanted. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you can use `SetParent` win32 function to set parent of your `Cmd window` to your `TabPage`. We can get the `Handle` of the `Cmd Window` by the property `MainWindowHandle` of the `Process` starting the `cmd.exe`. Here is the code you can try, however there is a little nasty problem that when you focus on the `Cmd window`, your form will look like lost focus:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int SetParent(IntPtr hwndChild, IntPtr hwndParent);
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex);
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex, long newLong);
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int flags);
public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Start cmd
        Process proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe"); 
        //HandleCreated event handler
        HandleCreated += (s,e) => {
          BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>
          {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);//wait for a while to make sure the MainWindowHandle is created
            int oldLong = GetWindowLong(proc.MainWindowHandle, -16);//GWL_STYLE = -16
            SetWindowLong(proc.MainWindowHandle, -16, oldLong & ~0xc00000);//WS_CAPTION = 0xC00000
            SetWindowPos(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, tabControl1.TabPages[0].Width, tabControl1.TabPages[0].Height + 40, 0x40);//SWP_SHOWWINDOw = 0X40                 
            SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, tabControl1.TabPages[0].Handle);                
          }));    
        };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. Thanks King this is what i wanted. Thanks for the direction i will try to work on this path  to meet my requirements.