# Interacting with the MS DOS window in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console-application, dos

I have to run a console program to transfer files from a local network drive to an off-site account. I'm at a standstill for automating this because the console program doesn't provide a password parameter.

Here is a general overview of the command line for the console program and its prompt for the password:

```
C:\> UploadTool [flags] Drive:\Accounts\AccountNumber\FilesFolder\
     UserName@host /RemoteDirectory/Folder
.
.
.
Password:
.
.
.
```

If the connection is successful, I’m prompted for a password in the command window (DOS), and then the upload starts.

I need some direction for what I could do in .NET to automate this workflow for multiple accounts. Does .NET include any libraries for interacting with the MS DOS screen? I need a way to run the console program and insert the password when prompted.

Comment: see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258416/shellexecute-equivalent-in-net

Comment: or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107683/controling-cmd-exe-from-winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Process` to start the console application. Then use `Process.StandardOutput` to read the output of the application and `Process.StandardInput` to send it input (the password).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx