# When using a console control on form1 why the output text in the console window is different and how to send commands?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I found the control in this codeproject site:

[Console Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335909/Embedding-a-Console-in-a-C-Application)

I added the dll in the form1 designer toolbox and dragged the console control to the form1.
But i'm facing two problems.

The first one is when i'm running the file opengrads.exe from the hard disk double click on it i see it's original output text like this as it should be:

[image: Console Window]

But when using the console control what i see inside is this strange text in red and white:

[image: Console Control1]

In both cases i can type inside the control the commands i need and they are working but why i see in the console control i dragged on form1 this red and white text ? Where is it came from ? Why i don't see the original text when running the opengrads.exe ?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Grads_Scripts
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string cmd = "";
        string exepath = @"C:\OpenGrADS\Contents\Cygwin\Versions\2.0.2.oga.2\i686\";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cmd = "set xsize 650 500";
            ProcessCommands();
        }

        private void ProcessCommands()
        {
            consoleControl1.StartProcess(exepath + "opengrads.exe", cmd);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Two problems with this console control:

1. Who i see different text and colors in the console control when it's running the opengrads.exe and not what it should show like in the original(first screenshot image) ?
2. I'm using the cmd variable i added a command to there "set xsize 650 500" but i don't see it taking effect nothing changed in the console control window. If i will type on my own the command it will do it but using the cmd variable it does nothing. How can i send commands to this consoleControl1 ?

Comment: why not just make a console app, not a winforms app?

Comment: I found how to do it without this control.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107683/controling-cmd-exe-from-winforms this is working i changed it a bit to what i need.